# Reference the subgrid in quote entity after revised with the same data

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I Have a `Subgrid` in `Quote` entity, in which there are records of my custom `entity`, And also the custom entity display in left side of the form,Because the custom `entity` has `N:1 relation` with quote.
Every `Quote` can have many of my custom entitiey  records.
It is ok,But when I `revise` the `Quote`, I want the same data and records of previous `subgrid` display in the new quote subgrid, as well as other fields that copy and `appear` from the previous subgrid.
How can I do that?
Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

When you create a revised quote through the UI, a new quote is created behind the scenes. You can thus create a plugin that listens for the `Create` eventoperation for Quote. In this plugin you can retrieve the original quote and clone the relationships between your custom entity and quote.

In the plugin you can check the value of the `revisionnumber` attribute to see if the quote in question is a revised quote.

Subsequently you can look in the `ParentContext` for the `QuoteId` value from the [`ReviseQuoteRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamics-crm2011/developers-guide/gg305901%28v%3Dcrm.5%29) to get the guid of the quote that the clone was initiated from. See [Catch the Revise Quote message inside a Plugin](https://www.crmanswers.net/2017/11/catch-revise-quote-message-inside-plugin.html) for an example of this.

You mention that the relationship from your custom entity to Quote is N:1. In this case you would need to either clone the custom records, or change the relationship to be N:N.